# Generic result enum with success array

Tags: swift, generics

I have this Result enum:

```
public enum Result<T>
{
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

I could get a `Response` object from the database, API, whatever and it looks like this:

```
public struct Response
{
    let result: Result<[Object]> // Object is some protocol or supertype
}
```

When I construct the Response object like this: `let successResponse = Response(result: .success(objects))` the compiler complains: `Member 'success' in 'Result<[Object]>' produces result of type 'Result<T>', but context expects 'Result<[Object]>'`. The `objects` type is `[Object]?` and is unwrapped with `guard ...`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could change your constraint to just `T: Object` and then make your case `case success([T])`.  There's really no reason your original enum shouldn't be able to have an array type as it's generic parameter, you should post your code from where you attempted that.

Comment: I don't think this Result type should care at all if it's holding an array. Just `enum Result<T> { case success(T), failure(Error) } ... let result: Result<[SomeObject]> = ...`

Comment: @Connor when I do it that way, I still get this error: `Member 'success' in 'Result<[Object]>' produces result of type 'Result<T>', but context expects 'Result<[Object]>'` when I call it like this:

`Response(result: .success(objects))`

Comment: Sounds like you have a mismatch in your generics somewhere. I'd need to see more of the code.

Comment: I edited my post to show more clearly what I'm trying to do, does this help you or do I need add more code?

Comment: The error is not related to the enum declaration. `T` can be anything even an array or dictionary

Comment: @jbehrens94 Can you add the code for the `objects` variable. looks like you're trying to pass an optional array to the `success` case.

Comment: @Mukesh That was actually it, I overlooked a check. Thank you so much!